# Django View Unit Tests when the View Accesses an Elasticsearch Index

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I have a Django view where a user fills out and submits a form. The data is taken from this form and a document is created in an Elasticsearch index.

My question, is how can I test this view without impacting my Elasticsearch index? It is a development index, but I would prefer not to muddle it with unit test data.

One option would be to create the record in the unit test and then delete it during tear down - but, if possible, I would really like to avoid touching the index at all.

Are there any other options?

Comment: Take a look at [unittest.mock](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/unittest.mock.html) for Python 3.x or [mock](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock) for 2.6+

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of different ways that could handle this:

- Stub out the loading of Elasticsearch depedency dynamically using `unittest.patch`
- Create some sort of "seam" into your view that allows the test to import the view and replace the elasticsearch class with a test implementation
- Define the elastic search class in settings as a module path and switch it out for the test runs (django actually does this with a lot of its depdendencies)